# Do I need to enable TRIM if I have a non-Intel/Samsung

Tags: ssd, trim

I read in one of the webupd8 articles that TRIM support, which was introduced in Ubuntu 14.04, by default only works for Intel and Samsung SSDs. What about other? I am using Dell XPS 13 Dev Edition laptop and the SSD is from a different manufacturer, so does TRIM work by default as well or I have to manually make a cron job file?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Everything is already installed.

The command to activate trim 1 time:

```
sudo fstrim -v /
```

It will take a while and then show the results. Example:

```
sudo fstrim -v /
[sudo] password for rinzwind: 
/: 93184647168 bytes were trimmed
```

And it is set up by default to run once a week for -supported devices-:

```
$ locate fstrim
/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim
/sbin/fstrim
```

If you check the cron job it is all explained:

```
$ more /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim 
#!/bin/sh
# call fstrim-all to trim all mounted file systems which support it
set -e

# This only runs on Intel and Samsung SSDs by default, as some SSDs with faulty
# firmware may encounter data loss problems when running fstrim under high I/O
# load (e. g.  https://launchpad.net/bugs/1259829). You can append the
# --no-model-check option here to disable the vendor check and run fstrim on
# all SSD drives.
exec fstrim-all
```

If the manual method works, you can add `--no-model-check` to the command at the end (`exec fstrim-all`) for it to activate.

---

The [link](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1259829) in the file is an interesting read. It also has a method to check if your [disc is bugged](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1259829/comments/44). A lot of the cheaper SSDs are faulty and could destroy data.

---

And to top it off: [this is a list of compatible hardware](http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/Host%20Bus%20Adapters/Host%20Bus%20Adapters%20Common%20Files/LSI_6Gb_SAS_SATA_HBA_Compatibility_List.pdf) (PDF download) including SSDs.

---

There is another method where you add `discard` to your fstab for permanent trimming. [Benchmarks](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/SSD/TRIM) (German) favor fstrim over [discard](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/core-1311-ssd-trimming).

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the explanation. Now it's all clear. I'll mark the answer as the right one in a few minutes. Cheers.

Comment: I didn't understand how to check if trim is working properly. Is there a script that checks it, or something else?

Comment: see the 1st command: `sudo fstrim -v /` this will error out if it is unsupported.

Comment: According to bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/util-linux/… fstrim-all will also work for OCZ, Patriot and Sandisk and is automatically activated on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty (See /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim)

Comment: @ChristianBenke cool. I would assume more and more will be added :) Link is broken though ;)

Comment: Ah, crap: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/util-linux/trusty/revision/103#debian/fstrim-all

Answer (score 0):

You can also force the TRIM (on filesystem like ext4/xfs) adding discard to the options of /etc/fstab entry. For example mine is:

```
/dev/sda3   /  ext4    errors=remount-ro,discard  0       1
```

If you use cryptsetup (for dmcrypt) you can also add discard in /etc/crypttab to force TRIM. Something like:

```
sda3_crypt UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx none luks,discard
```