# Can I 'reset' an SSD to improve its performance?

Tags: ssd, trim

I think my SSD is getting a bit slower with time. I think it just might be the case, if [TRIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM) is not supported by my version of Ubuntu.

I have an Intel 520 SSD in a Thinkpad laptop.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit and I'm going to do a fresh install of 14.04 LTS 64-bit. While doing a reinstall, could I somehow 'reset' an SSD to its pristine state, thus restoring its performance?

Comment: @Rinzwind ok, but isn't there anything I'll have to do _before_ installing 14.04 with TRIM support? Like, run a special command to clear all data or reset SSD to factory defaults, or something?

Comment: ok, thanks for letting me know of `fstrim` command. I think this is  technically an answer to my question, even if you didn't quite spell it out. By the way, I just ran it on my 13.10. I wonder what additional _support_ the 14.04 will add: running it weekly automatically?

Comment: Of course! Thank you very much! Good to know that the supported ones are just the SSD's I considered (Intel and Samsung, basically; well, I have Intel and I think I'll buy Samsung in the future)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While doing a reinstall, could I somehow 'reset' an SSD to its pristine state, thus restoring its performance?

Do a re-install with format and this will be taken care of.

14.04 will have trim installed by default. It will be turned off by default since only specific intel and samsung ssd have been tested and have been confirmed working (they took the cautious route here: if it was not confirmed working it is not activated).

More on the inner workings (setup, activate and commands) here: [Do I need to enable TRIM if I have a non-Intel/Samsung](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449204/do-i-need-to-enable-trim-if-i-have-a-non-intel-samsung/449207#449207)